# How do I create a link in a views.php which uses the link variable defined in the options.php

Tags: php

How do I create a link in a views.php which uses the link variable defined in the options.php

I've added the "Link" info here ... basically just copied the code from the button shortcode of another file which uses a link / button

Here is the options.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined( 'FW' ) ) {
    die( 'Forbidden' );
}

$options = array(
    'title'  => array(
        'type'   => 'text',
        'value' => '',
        'label' => __('Title', 'fw'),
        'desc'  => __('Add section title', 'fw')
    ),

    'box' => array(
        'type'  => 'addable-box',
        'value' => array(
            array(
                'title' => '',
            )
        ),
        'label' => __('Process', 'fw'),
        'desc'  => __('Add a process', 'fw'),
        'template' => '{{=title}}',
        'box-options' => array(
            'title' => array(
                'label' => __('Title','fw'),
                'desc'  => __( 'Enter the process title', 'fw' ),
                'type' => 'text'
            ),
            'link'   => array(
                'label' => __( 'Button Link', 'fw' ),
                'desc'  => __( 'Where should your button link to', 'fw' ),
                'type'  => 'text',
                'value' => '#' ),

            'desc' => array(
                'label' => __('Description', 'fw'),
                'type'   => 'textarea',
                'desc' => __('Enter the process content','fw') ),

            'icon_box' => array(
                'type'  => 'multi-picker',
                'label' => false,
                'desc'  => false,
                'picker' => array(
                    'icon_type'       => array(
                        'label'   => __( 'Icon', 'fw' ),
                        'desc'    => __( 'Choose icon type', 'fw' ),
                        'attr'    => array( 'class' => 'fw-checkbox-float-left' ),
                        'type'    => 'radio',
                        'value'   => 'awesome',
                        'choices' => array(
                            'awesome' => __( 'Font Awesome', 'fw' ),
                            'custom' => __( 'Custom Icon Class', 'fw' )
                        )
                    ),
                ),
                'choices' => array(
                    'awesome' => array(
                        'icon'          => array(
                            'type'  => 'icon',
                            'label' => __( '', 'fw' ),
                            'desc'  => __( 'Choose icon', 'fw' )
                        ),
                    ),
                    'custom' => array(
                        'icon'          => array(
                            'type'  => 'text',
                            'label' => __( '', 'fw' ),
                            'desc'  => __( 'Add custom icon class', 'fw' )
                        ),
                    )
                )
            ),

            'box_type' => array(
                'type'  => 'multi-picker',
                'label' => false,
                'desc'  => false,
                'picker' => array(
                    'message_type'  => array(
                        'type'  => 'select',
                        'value' => '',
                        'label' => __('Background', 'fw'),
                        'desc'  => __('Select process background type', 'fw'),
                        'choices' => array(
                            'color-1-default' => __('Type 1', 'fw'),
                            'color-2' => __('Type 2', 'fw'),
                            'color-3' => __('Type 3', 'fw'),
                            'color-4' => __('Type 4', 'fw'),
                            'custom' => __('Custom Type', 'fw'),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'choices' => array(
                    'custom' => array(
                        'bg_color' => array(
                            'type'  => 'rgba-color-picker',
                            'value' => '',
                            'label' => __( 'Bg Color', 'fw' ),
                            'desc'  => __( 'Choose process bg color', 'fw' ),
                        ),
                        'text_color' => array(
                            'type'  => 'color-picker',
                            'value' => '',
                            'label' => __( 'Text Color', 'fw' ),
                            'desc'  => __( 'Choose process text color', 'fw' ),
                        ),
                    )
                )
            ),
        ),
    ),

    'class'          => array(
        'type'  => 'text',
        'label' => __( 'Custom Class', 'fw' ),
        'desc'  => __( 'Enter a custom CSS class', 'fw' ),
        'help'  => __( 'You can use this class to further style this shortcode by adding your custom CSS', 'fw' ),
    ),

);
```

And here is the views.php

```
  <?php if ( ! defined( 'FW' ) ) {
    die( 'Forbidden' );
}

?>
<?php if(!empty($atts['title'])):?>
    <div class="procces-text-wrapper">
        <div class="w-container">
            <div class="tittle-wrapper">
                <h3 class="blue"><?php echo fw_theme_translate(esc_html($atts['title'])); ?></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(!empty($atts['box'])):?>
    <div class="process-work <?php echo esc_attr($atts['class']);?>">
        <?php foreach($atts['box'] as $box): ?>
            <?php
                //get box type
                $box_class = ($box['box_type']['message_type'] == 'custom') ? '' : $box['box_type']['message_type'];

                //custom type colors
                $bg_color = empty($box_class) ? 'style="background-color:'.$box['box_type']['custom']['bg_color'].';"' : '';
                $text_color = empty($box_class) ? 'style="color:'.$box['box_type']['custom']['text_color'].'"' : '';

                //get arrow type
                if($box_class == 'color-2')
                    $arrow = '<div class="arrow-proccess"></div>';
                elseif($box_class == 'color-3')
                    $arrow = '<div class="arrow-proccess color-2"></div>';
                elseif($box_class == 'color-4')
                    $arrow = '<div class="arrow-proccess color-3"></div>';
                else
                    $arrow = '';

                //get icon
                $icon = ($box['icon_box']['icon_type'] == 'awesome') ? $box['icon_box']['awesome']['icon'] : $box['icon_box']['custom']['icon'];

            ?>




            <div class="procces-wrapper <?php echo esc_attr($box_class);?>" data-ix="process-effect" <?php echo ($bg_color);?>>
                <?php echo do_shortcode($arrow); ?>
                <div>

                    <?php if(!empty($icon)) : ?>
                        <div class="procc-ico" data-ix="move-titte-procces" <?php echo ($text_color);?>>
                            <div class="w-embed"><i class="<?php echo esc_attr($icon);?>"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif;?>


                    <?php if(!empty($box['title'])):?>
                        <div class="process-title" data-ix="move-titte-procces">
                            <h4 class="h-process" <?php echo ($text_color);?>><?php echo fw_theme_translate(esc_html($box['title']));?></h4>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif;?>


                    <?php if(!empty($box['desc'])):?>
                        <div class="sp-process" data-ix="move-process-text">
                            <p class="white" <?php echo ($text_color);?>><?php echo fw_theme_translate(esc_html($box['desc']));?></p>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif;?>

                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

I want to make the title section.... a clickable link that refers to the 'link' defined in the options.php.

```
 <?php if(!empty($box['title'])):?>
                        <div class="process-title" data-ix="move-titte-procces">
                            <h4 class="h-process" <?php echo ($text_color);?>><?php echo fw_theme_translate(esc_html($box['title']));?></h4>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif;?>
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to make a templating system so, if i'm right this is your answer:
1- make a function that look inside the view.php file then convert the specified words with the defined one .
2- include the function into the file with require_once or include_once.
I make this code for you:
3-create a file with any name then write your stufe into it as an array like this:

```
      <?php

$lang=array(
"lang"=>"ar",
"direction"=>"rtl",
"date_type"=>"hjri",
"site_title"=>"my site name",
"translator"=>"your name ",
"version"=>"0.1");
```

Then include it into your function file using function like this:

```
      function replace_word_with_array_element($file,$template){

//the file -which has the words array to replace -
        require_once($file);
      //we assign the file -which has the template html and etc - to variable named $tpl
        $tpl= file_get_contents($template);

 //my array name is $lang so i'll work with this name
$patt_rep=$lang;
   if($patt_rep !==false){
//this function make an array with the original array key values
            $patt = array_keys($patt_rep);
//create an empty array called $pattern to save the form that when it find the replacement will be done ! 
            $pattern =array();
//looping the $patt array -array with the original array key values-
            foreach($patt as $p){
          //add the pattern into every keys of the array - the pattern is {word to be replaced}
                $pattern[] ="/{".$p."}/";
            }//end foreach
         //active this if you want to see the new array
            //print_r($pattern);

    //we create  an array and we call it $repalcement to save the original array values into it.
            $repalcement=array_values($patt_rep);
            //active this if you want to see the new array
            //print_r($repalcement);
           //The Most important part of code is this function that replace the pattern with my words 
//(the pattern array , the words array , the string that has our template)
            $tpl=preg_replace($pattern, $repalcement,$tpl);

           //the function  will return our template as a string
            return $tpl;


      }//end of the function
```

now in your view.php file just include the function then echo it like this:

```
      echo replace_word_with_array_element("lang.php","header.php");
      echo replace_word_with_array_element("lang.php","content.php");
      echo replace_word_with_array_element("lang.php","footer.php");
```

and the header file will be like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8"/>
                <title>{site_title}</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="{style}">
            </head>
            <body class="main_admin_body">
                <div id="admin_wrapper">
                    <!--the content START here!-->
```